# Conditions met but code doesn't executes (Ruby)

Tags: ruby, console-application

Regarding my code here : https://repl.it/BmCr/1
When the player loses it always says the player.
The problem comes somewhere from here :

```
def subit_attaque(degats_recus)
  # A faire:
  # - Réduit les points de vie en fonction des dégats reçus
  # - Affiche ce qu'il s'est passé
  # - Détermine si la personne est toujours en_vie ou non
  @points_de_vie -= degats_recus
  puts "#{@nom} a perdu #{degats_recus} points de vie"
  if @points_de_vie > 0
    @en_vie = true
  else
    @en_vie = false
  end
end
```

"@en_vie = false" never happens even if hero life points are below 0
Does someone know from the problem could come from ?

Comment: I've checked with a puts statement and the "if" is never run, why does this happen ?

Comment: Well, what exactly is `@points_de_vie` before the method changes it? What is it after? What is `degats_recus`?

Comment: Didn't you look at my entire code here :  https://repl.it/BmCr/1 ?   "@point_de_vie" is equal to 100 before the hero gots attaqued by ennemi, after a few turns it will often go below 0 but even if it's over 100 the "@point_de_vie" is never checked

Comment: @webdev Welcome to SO! Linking to external code repos is *strongly* discouraged on SO. Shrink your code to a *minimal complete* example, see [mcve].

Comment: Ok my problem was somewhere else, the code above is completely ok, finally i fixed it

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is outside of the code referenced here or the linked code. This method works fine. You don't call it anywhere in the linked code. Print out the values of `@points_de_vie` before and after this method alters it. I imagine you'll find that its initial value isn't what you expect.

Comment: Ok i checked, it's even worse i thinked. None of the puts statement shows something. I think i don't use it correctly, it's like the entire function isn't working